# How to use other applications to send pictures?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

How to you make it so if a user does something, it asks them how they want to do it and it brings them to that application? Like if you go "Share" a photo or video it pops up a list with all apps that can do that for you like facebook or text or email , ect.? I am asking how to have my app use other apps, not them use mine.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by targeting the intent filter that the other apps use.

For example, if I want to share a picture, I can do this:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");    
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/sdcard/test.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image"));
```

Then you will get a popup to choose the app to use for this action.

Comment: you pass it as the second param in putExtra()

Comment: "you pass it as the second param in putExtra()" well I tried that with no success.

Comment: What's the results? What's happening? Can you paste the code you tried.

Comment: Should be as simple as share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, `Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/test.jpg"));` - but will Android download the test.jpg then?